multithreading in c++ not working properly
I am trying to run two threads. The first one will run infinitely and the other one will run when mutex lock on first will be cleared.
I don't want to change the basic structure of code like, the loop should be there in one thread. and it should be infinite.
the problem is I am unable to process thread2.
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>

std::mutex myMutex;

void thread1Function() {
    std::cout << "Thread 1 started." << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
            std::cout << "t1" << std::endl;
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
    std::cout << "Thread 1 finished." << std::endl;
}

void thread2Function() {
    std::cout << "Thread 2 started." << std::endl;
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
        std::cout << "t2" << std::endl;
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout << "Thread 2 finished." << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::thread t1(thread1Function);
    std::thread t2(thread2Function);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}

This is the basic code of my implementation. This code just prints the data as t2, t1, t1... and only t1 till loop ends.
can somebody help me to solve this issue ? both threads must have to run.

This is unclear to me. Consider adding the actual output of the program and explaining how it is different from what you expect.

Charlie_57 I think you may be misinterpreting the output. As you said, it prints t2 so this means thread 2 did in fact acquire the mutex. If you are puzzled as to why Thread 2 finished is printed after Thread 1 finished it's because 5*100ms < 1s. Try looping thread 1 20 times instead of 5 and you'll see the difference.

"This code just prints the data as t2, t1, t1... and only t1 till loop ends." This looks perfectly fine to me. What would you expect it to print?

Please show the actual output this produces. Also, provide and explain the expected output. I don't see anything wrong with what you describe, so it's hard to tell what "this issue" is that you're referring to.

You hold the mutex to output "t1" and "t2", but you don't hold it to output "Thread 1 started." etc. You don't need a mutex to protect std::cout unless you std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)

Can you give a sample output of what "The first one will run infinitely and the other one will run when mutex lock on first will be cleared." would look like? n.b. thread 1 won't run infinitely, you exit the loop after 5 iterations

Looks like a classic case of starvation. Mutexes in most threading libraries are not fair. That is to say, when two threads both want to lock the same mutex, there is no guarantee that the thread that's been waiting the longest will be the one to which it is awarded.
In fact, the opposite often is true. A design goal of most desktop/server/mobile operating systems is to make the most efficient possible use of the CPUs. In both of your threads, the very next thing that happens after the thread releases the mutex is, it tries to lock it again. In your example, if thread 2 is asleep, waiting for the mutex when thread 1 releases it, it's highly likely that thread 1 will acquire the mutex again before the OS even considers waking thread 2 up. More of the available CPU cycles get used by user-mode processes and less of them are "wasted" by the OS if the OS scheduling strategy minimizes the number of times it has to "switch contexts" (i.e., put one thread to sleep, and wake another up.)
The way to avoid this kind of starvation is to minimize the amount of time each thread spends while keeping one or more mutexes locked. Your threads do practically 100% of their work with the mutex locked. In some real programs, even doing 1% of a thread's work with a mutex locked potentially causes performance problems.
